# Parallel Programming C# 4.0 Task.StartNew

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I am trying to process 2 independent tasks using the new .NET 4.0 Task Parallel Library

```
inputList1 is List<CustomObject>

inputList2 is List<DateTime>

List<double> firstCall = GetDoubleListing(inputList1, inputList2); 
List<double> secondCall = GetAnotherListing(inputList3, inputList2);
```

inputList2 is common in both the calls ( it is a read only list ).

I tried to use the following code but kept getting exceptions

```
Task[] tsk = {
    Task<List<double>>.Factory.StartNew(GetDoubleListing(inputList1, inputList2)),
    Task<List<double>>.Factory.StartNew(GetAnotherListing(inputList3, inputList2));
};
```

Can someone guide me as to how to pass parameters and how to enable Task Parallel Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you just want the `GetDoubleListing()` and `GetAnotherListing()` calls done in parallel.  The overloads for [`StartNew()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx) require delegates.  As the parameters are not changing, you can make the calls using lambdas like this:

```
Task[] tsk =
{
    Task<List<double>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDoubleListing(inputList1, inputList2)),
    Task<List<double>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAnotherListing(inputList3, inputList2));
};
```